# Image captions and wrapping

Tags: html

What's the best way to add a caption below an image?  The image and its caption will be floated right, and the text on the caption needs to wrap -- a 200x200px image shouldn't have a caption of width 800px.

I would strongly prefer a solution that allows me to update images (with different widths) without changing the CSS or markup.

*For reasons beyond my control* the image itself will also be floated right, but this should not be too problematic.

---

The image code is

```
<div class="floatright">
  <img alt="foo" src="bar.png" height="490" border="0" width="800">
</div>
```

and I can wrap this with HTML/CSS as needed.  No JS on this page.

Comment: Can you show sample mark-up? Are you able to *change* the mark-up? Can you use [tag:css], or [tag:javascript]?

Comment: @David Thomas: Added to the question.  No Javascript, but I can add HTML and inline CSS around the `<div>` above.

Comment: Are you always going to explicitly specify the image width and height like that, or is the plan to simply drop in an image and have the caption format according to the image size?

Comment: @Town: Drop in an image.  The whole `<div>` with image sizes will be added and my code won't 'see' it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```css
figure {
  display: table;
}

figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/50" />
  <figcaption>This is a caption of slightly longer length. It should wrap, regardless of the size of the image.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[image]

You can substitute `figure` and `figcaption` for `div` and `p`, or whatever other containers float your semantic boat.

Shameless plug: I blogged about this problem and [my solution here](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2013/properly-aligning-and-wrapping-image-captions/), if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QLcRC/ ?

Comment: Hmm... nice.  But the caption overlaps the surrounding text.

Comment: OK, I was able to make this work by wrapping everything you provided with another `<div>`, then adding as its last child a `<p>` with `clear:right`.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to make one `<div>` with an `<img>` tag and `<p>` tag.

```
<div class="photo">
  <img src="someimage.jpg">
  <p>my caption
</div>
```

Now you simply set two styles. One for the img tag and the other for the p tag for the photo class.

Create a class name it photo:

```
.photo {float: right;width: 210px;margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;}
img.photo {float: right;margin-left: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;border: 1px solid #666;
```

padding: 10px;}

Conclusion:
1. A div with an `<img>` tag and a `<p>` tag.
2. Div should have one class with different styles for `<p>` and `<img>` tag.

Comment: I won't know the width of a given image.  (For one thing, I'll use it on several images of different widths.)

Answer (score 2):

You may use also use the [HTML5 figure and figcaption elements](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) and style those as @Wasim suggested.

```
<figure>
    <img src="/test.jpg" alt="a test-image">
    <figcaption>Description</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Another (not-so-cross-browser-savvy) approach is to use the img title-attribute and insert it as a pseudo-element via CSS:

```
#content img[title]:after {
    content: "[" counter(image) "] " attr(title);
    counter-increment: image;
    display: block;
    text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure HTML/CSS inline styled.

```html
<div style="width:40%;
            margin-right:6%;
            float: left;">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Papilio_machaon_Mitterbach_01.jpg/500px-Papilio_machaon_Mitterbach_01.jpg" width="100%">
  <p style="color:gray; 
            background-color:#eee;
            margin-top:-4px;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            text-align:center;">

    <span style="padding-right:10px;
                 padding-left:10px;"> Butterfly </span></p>

</div>

<!-- NEXT ONE -->

<div style="width:40%;
            float: left;">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Papilio_machaon_Mitterbach_01.jpg/500px-Papilio_machaon_Mitterbach_01.jpg" width="100%">
  <p style="color:gray; 
            background-color:#eee;
            margin-top:-4px;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            text-align:center;">

    <span style="padding-right:10px;
                 padding-left:10px;"> Butterfly </span></p>

</div>

<div style="clear:all;"></div>

<!-- NEXT ROW -->


<div style="width:40%;
            margin-right:6%;
            float: left;">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Papilio_machaon_Mitterbach_01.jpg/500px-Papilio_machaon_Mitterbach_01.jpg" width="100%">
  <p style="color:gray; 
            background-color:#eee;
            margin-top:-4px;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            text-align:center;">

    <span style="margin-top:0px;
                 padding-right:10px;
                 padding-left:10px;"> Butterfly </span></p>

</div>

<!-- NEXT ONE -->

<div style="width:40%;
            float: left;">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Papilio_machaon_Mitterbach_01.jpg/500px-Papilio_machaon_Mitterbach_01.jpg" width="100%">
  <p style="color:gray; 
            background-color:#eee;
            margin-top:-4px;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            text-align:center;">

    <span style="padding-right:10px;
                 padding-left:10px;"> Butterfly </span></p>

</div>

<div style="clear:all; height:100px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with current browsers. atlavis solution is the most simple. Until all browsers implement figure tag, then Feeela's way would work. But even then it would not be backwards compatible. I searched this issue for 3 days straight and I really hate the guys that made CSS decided to strip tables which were backwards compatible.

You could use the `display: table-cell` property on the class. But that is not supported by IE 6 or 7.