# Getting caption text wrap to work in IE

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, caption

I've been trying to find a solution for this that works in IE or getting IE to play nice (ha!).

What I want to do: Create a div that contains an image and a caption but not allow the caption to stretch the div wider than the image, instead break the text line (wrap), and without having to specify a width so that this can be used dynamically.

What I've found so far that works in browsers other than IE:

```
<div id="featured-image">
<img src="images/cats-brenda.jpg" alt="Litter of Kittens"/><br/>
<span class="caption">Litter of kittens at the Sacramento County Animal 
Shelter (Image by: Brenda Bongiorno)</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#featured-image {
display: table; min-width: 1px; float: left; margin-right: 10px;}
#featured-image .caption {display: table-caption; caption-side: bottom;}
```

This works perfectly, just not in IE. Instead, in IE, because the caption is wider than the image, it stretches the entire div to match the caption, not the image, pushing into the article.

I'd post screenshots, but I have to "have 10 reputation" to do that :(

Comment: This doesn't work just in IE7, right?

Comment: could try `max-width:100%`

Comment: I already tried that Dominic B-c :( And it seems to work in all IE's 9 and lower. I also have a div that is not minding it's place and stretching 100% width of the container rather than avoiding the table (or div).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question works in IE, too, but not in IE 7 (or older), due to lack of [support to CSS table display](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

There are [many ways](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html) to present images with captions, but with the given requirements, if you want IE 7 support too, the only reasonable solution is to use an HTML table:

```
<table>
<caption align="bottom" style="text-align: left">
Litter of kittens at the Sacramento County Animal 
Shelter (Image by: Brenda Bongiorno)</caption>
<tr><td>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/animals" alt="Litter of Kittens"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This helped a little but now I have a div that I created for quotes spanning the entire width. Well, it didn't work before, but I guess that's a whole other issue. :)

Comment: Although this is the official html5 solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523560/image-captions-and-wrapping#19458847 The above is better for users working in ckeditor or tinymce due to those JS editors enhanced table management. Using this format lets them edit captions and change table align natively versus not being able to do much with <figure><caption> unless they drop to the source code.